# HikaiCP : How to see the connection pool size?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hikaricp

I have a java/spring project and i use hikaricp with Hibernate. I add Hikari to manage connection pool size. In hibernate.properties, i add :

```
hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
```

I don't know how to check the size of connection while running my application ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each database type has some tables to check the sessions (active, inactive, etc..).

For example, you could execute in Oracle a SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM V$Session WHERE Status=‘ACTIVE’ AND UserName IS NOT NULL;
```

Or, if you are using any tools like SQL Developer, you can use some function like Monitor Sessions.